# Unable to evaluate expression in PCLStorage

Tags: windows-8, portable-class-library

I'm using PCLStorage in my Win8/Wp8 apps, but for simplicity I'll direct my question only for Win8.

I've referenced the PCLStorage package in my Win8 project and also a PCL project. In my PCL project, I'm creating a document management class to handle the saving/retrieving of files.

```
    private IFileSystem LocalFileSystem { get; set; }
    protected IFolder RootFolder { get; set; }
    protected IFolder RoamingFolder { get; set; }

    public DocStorageManager()
    {
        LocalFileSystem = FileSystem.Current;
        RootFolder = LocalFileSystem.LocalStorage;
        RoamingFolder = LocalFileSystem.RoamingStorage;
    }
```

When debugging I see that `LocalFileSystem` gets set to an instance of `PCLStorage.WinRTFileSystem`. `RootFolder` and `RoamingFolder` however show up as *Could not evaluate expression.*

Now if I go into the Immediate Window and type `FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage` I get a valid WinRTFolder with a path to my local storage:

```
FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage
Name = "LocalState"
    [PCLStorage.WinRTFolder]: Name = "LocalState"
    Name: "LocalState"
    Path: "C:\\Users\\myuser\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\1957d424-34d5-4856-9186-4a64dfaf1ae7_q5jzzq53vdxma\\LocalState"
```

*However* I cannot simply assign `RootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage` because it then says *Could not evaluate expression* again.

It sounds like there is a fundamental behavior I don't understand. How should I structure this to use it as I need to?

many thanks!

Comment: this looks to be a non-issue. While the value cannot be resolved when debugging, it looks like it is correctly evaluated at runtime. This only makes debugging slightly more difficult, but still manageable.